# receiving transform from [/robot_state_publisher] that differed from ROS time

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, frequency

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ALL I'm beginner to ros

I have mounted zed camera on my youBot robot and connected the tf tree as follows:

![image description](tf frames)

when I visualize in rviz the camera only works when I choose the arm_link_5 or base_link_zed and its children as fixed frame and I want it to work when using odom as fixed frame since I have a linked tf tree.

when running roswtf i get:

```
receiving transform from [/robot_state_publisher] that differed from ROS time by 566050.175641s
```

so is the problem with the transfer frequency and if so how can i fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343185/receiving-transform-from-%5B/robot_state_publisher%5D-that-differed-from-ros-time/) by [arafatsadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/46446/arafatsadasd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-02-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-04**:
Could you check your screenshots? You didn't have enough karma before, so they were never attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

fixed it by synchronising the time.

---

Originally posted by [arafatsadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/46446/arafatsadasd/) with karma: 11 on 2020-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gates](https://answers.ros.org/users/40632/gates/) on 2021-09-01**:
can you please be more specific? How did you synchronize the time?

**Comment by [tomkimsour](https://answers.ros.org/users/73888/tomkimsour/) on 2022-03-23**:
I know it has been some time now but could you explain how you did this ?

**Comment by [arafatsadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/46446/arafatsadasd/) on 2022-03-24**:
My camera was connected to nvidia jetson and my robot has its own computer, after connecting ros between both devices I noticed that the time is not the same(like by minutes) so I used ntpdate to update the time on both